# TimePicker in Preferences Activity and OnTimeChangedListener (Not working)

Tags: java, android, timepicker

I want to have time picker in preferences activity. It looks like this:

[image]

Then if user clicks on "time", it pops up this dialog:

[image]

This is EXACTLY what i wanted. But there are few things to notice:

1. Dialog is my custom dialog referenced by XML

   ```
     <TimePicker
       android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   ```
2. My preferences XML

   ```
   <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Checkbox" android:summary="Checkbox"/>
   <EditTextPreference android:summary="time" android:dialogTitle="Hello" android:dialogLayout="@layout/preflayout" />
   ```
3. My Java code:

   public static class TestSettings extends PreferenceActivity implements TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener {

   ```
       TimePicker tp;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);
           tp = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

       }

       @Override
       public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

           if(view.getId() == R.id.timePicker1) {
           Log.i("STATIC", "hour "+hourOfDay+"minute "+minute);
           }
       }

   }
   ```

For some reason OnTimeChangedListener does not fire, when i set time. I dont know if this is the right approach to program time picker this way in preferences screen, but i need it exactly like that. Anyway, i don't know why OnTimeChangedListener is not working. Any ideas?

Maybe i need to use another approach to program time picker in preference activity?

Suggestions appriciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [setOnTimeChangedListener(this)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#setOnTimeChangedListener%28android.widget.TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener%29), probably in your `onCreate()` method, like this:

```
tp.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);
```

Comment: Hmm. It crashes the program. (NULLPOITEREXCEPTION).

Comment: You added it to the code after the `tp = ...` line, right?  Is `tp` null at that point?

Comment: first i find the view (findviewbyid), and then i set listener which is null exactly on this line:

   tp.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);

Comment: OK clearly I'm missing something.  Perhaps you need to set the listener in a `protected View onCreateDialogView()` method?

Comment: I think i used bad approach for this. I just checked and i need to call "setContentView();" method before i can check for views (findviewbyid).

Answer (score 1):

I have to use custom dialog preference to handle TimePicker on my preference activity.

**TimePickerDialog.java**

```
public class TimePickerDialog extends DialogPreference{
    Context context;
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
TimePicker timePicker;
private final static String TAG = "TIME_DIALOG_PREFERENCE";
private Listener timeListener;
String key;


   public TimePickerDialog (Context context) {
        this(context, null);
        this.context=context;
    }

    public TimePickerDialog (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        this.context=context;
    }

    public TimePickerDialog (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);

            timeListener=(Listener) context;
            this.context=context;

        setPositiveButtonText("Set");
        setNegativeButtonText("Cancel");

     }

     public void setListener(Listener listener){
        timeListener =listener;
     }

     @Override
     public View onCreateDialogView(){      
        timePicker =  new TimePicker(context);
        timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
        return timePicker;
     }

     public void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult){
        if(timeListener!=null && positiveResult){
            timeListener.setTime( key,timePicker.getCurrentHour(),timePicker.getCurrentMinute());   
        }
    }


     public interface Listener{
        public void setTime(String key,int hour,int minute);
      }

}
```

The dialog is called from xml file **preference** layout:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Schedule" >
    <com.tuxuri.timepicker.TimePickerDialog
        android:defaultValue="08:00"
        android:key="schedule_start_time"
        android:showDefault="true"
        android:summary="When to start"
        android:title="Start time" /> 

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Then anything invoked by TimePickerDialog will be implemented in PreferenceActivity :

```
 public class UserPreference extends PreferenceActivity implements TimePickerDialog.Listener {

     @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preference);
     }

     @Override
      public void setTime(String key, int hour, int minute) {
            Log.v(TAG,key+"-"+hour+":"+minute);
       }
}
```

Comment: i used your solution but there are error on this line public class UserPreference extends PreferenceActivity implements TimePickerDialog.Listener { ....... TimePickerDialog.Listener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this);

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - timePicker cannot be resolved to a variable 
 - The constructor TimePickerDialog(SettingsActivity) is undefined

Comment: I  have added another constructor. It should be work.

Comment: How do I get timing in MainActivity or another activity, need it the earliest ..thanks